# “Who I really am” VS. “who I am really”?

Tags: adverbs, inversion

If I said

> - Do you know who I really am?

Could we move “really” after am to go like:

> - Do you know who I am really?

Is the inversion happened in the second sentence acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

It is acceptable, but the meaning would be different. In the first sentence, you're saying something to this effect:

> Do you know who in fact I am? Do you realize who I am? Do you understand that I'm the boss here. I could get you fired in the blink of an eye.

In the second sentence, you actually need a comma before *really*. Here's how I would interpret it:

> Do you know who I am, really? Really, do you know that? Oh my gosh, I can't believe that. Are you for real? How do you know that?

It is very difficult to explain the difference between these two usages of *really* in writing. This is something you need to hear. And a lot actually depends on how one says it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have two questions; Does that mean i can’t make the second sentence stay as it is without adding a comma? Secondly, is there any difference between saying: I really am the boss , **and** I am really the boss? If there is no deference, so I think in my two sentences with inversion  would not be even a single difference. What do you think?

Comment: First question: I added a comma there because to me it just feels like it belongs there. In a real-life conversation, there are, of course, no commas. It all comes down to stress and intonation.

Comment: Second question: there definitely is a difference. **I really am the boss** means that it's an undisputed fact that I'm the boss. **I am really the boss?** expresses the idea that you've just found out that you're the boss (probably somebody made you the boss) and now you're surprised by it.